# Linux command substitution order

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

I'm confused with the command substitution. I think command substitution as like a programming language macro. The sub shell is executed first and the `$(...)` is substituted with it's standard output, before the parent command is evaluated. But is this all the truth?

When I try to execute the following command

`echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 $(echo 'echo | tac')`

I would except to see the following output

```
8 9
6 7
4 5
2 3
0 1
```

But instead get this

```
| tac 0 1
| tac 2 3
| tac 4 5
| tac 6 7
| tac 8 9
```

So what causes `| tac` to be captured as an argument to the echo, and not as part of the command line? What is the exact mechanism and order, how the command line and command substitution is parsed, scoped and evaluated? Is it possible at all to build command lines dynamically in Linux in a metaprogramming style of way?

**Edit**

I know I could just use `echo {0..9}| xargs -n 2 | tac`. This question is theoretical, I'm interested why the sub shell example doesn't produce the same result

Comment: `$(echo 'echo | tac')` - the 1st `echo` is pointless here

Comment: It would be next to impossible to work with untrusted data (filenames, etc) safely if the syntax were what you intuit. See an overview at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashParser

Comment: unless you use the `-I` option, `xargs` will always append the arguments it creates from stdin onto the END of the command-lines it executes.   xargs is doing **exactly** what you are telling it to do.  it doesn't produce the same result as in your Edit because it's a completely different command.  This question is like asking "why don't I get the same output from `printf '%s %s\n' {0..9} | tac` as I do from `printf '| tac %s %s\n' {0..9}`?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The genesis of the issue you are seeing is due to the way tokenization happens of a command line. In this particular case, much before the `$(echo 'echo | tac')` is expanded, the shell has already figured out that you intend to run a command (`echo {…}`) and pass it's output via a pipe (`|`) to another command (`xargs -n 2 $(…)`).

Then in the next stage does the filling in of `$(…)` and brace expansion `{…}` happens to generate the actual commands to be run. And in this stage if it results in a pipe character, so what, it's too late and it's clearly missed the bus.

Now it will be treated as not as a special metacharacter, but will be included in the `xargs` command line as just any ordinary (=> non-metachar) char.

Should you want to take another shot at it, then you need to `eval` it.

```
eval "echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 $(echo 'echo | tac')"
```

This will output what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

besides Roman said, your commnand should be like this

`echo {0..9}| xargs -n 2 | tac`

this produces

```
8 9
6 7 
4 5
2 3
0 1
```

with the pointless $(echo 'echo') this causes the error

PS. For the long answer, `|` redirects the output from one command to the next one, so `echo {0..9}` produces:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

`xargs -n 2` takes that input and produces

```
0 1
2 3
4 5 
6 7
8 9
```

and finally `tac` takes that input and produces the reverse expresion:

```
8 9
6 7
4 5
2 3
0 1
```

I hope this is a bit clearer.

**EDIT:**

```
echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 $(echo 'echo | tac')
+ echo 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
++ echo 'echo | tac'
+ xargs -n 2 echo '|' tac
| tac 0 1
| tac 2 3
| tac 4 5
| tac 6 7
| tac 8 9
```

This is the command that you are sending to bash with your initial sintax, it's pretty clear what's happening, at the end you are sending `xargs -n 2 echo '|' tac`

Comment: I know this stuff and the question is theoretical. Read the last paragraph of my question. I'm interested why command substitution example doesn't produce the same result (not saying there is any sane reason to do this)

Comment: This is good example of the correct usage and what goes wrong, but doesn't explain the reason. Upvoted for effort

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being redundant
(but I don’t see where anybody else has said this plainly),
the reason why your

```
echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 $(echo 'echo | tac')
```

command does what it does is that it is equivalent to

```
echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 'echo' '|' 'tac'
```

Compare to

```
echo {0..9} | xargs -n 2 echo foo bar
```

This happens because the `$(echo …)` is evaluated
after the overall structure of the command line
(`echo (something) | xargs (args)`)
has been parsed, and so the output from `$(echo …)` can only
add argument(s) to the `xargs` command. 
To do what you want the way that you want to do it, you would need to say

```
echo {0..9} | eval xargs -n 2 $(echo 'echo | tac')
```

Note that `eval` can be dangerous. 
Search this site for warnings about it, and heed them.